# Erratic auto-scrolling in JList

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jscrollpane, jlist

I'm trying to create a JList that allows you to re-order items in the list by dragging them. This is working OK, except the auto-scrolling behavior is very jerky and erratic. When I grab an item in the list and drag it to the bottom of the list, I expect it to scroll smoothly and continuously, but what I actually get is that it scrolls a few pixels and stops. If I jiggle the mouse cursor around the edge of the JList, then it continues scrolling a few pixels at a time, but clearly this is not acceptable behavior.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to fix this?

In case it matters, I'm running Java 6 on Mac OS X 10.8.3.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;

public class DraggableJList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int count=200;
                String[] elements = new String[count];
                for(int n=0; n<count; n++ ) {
                    elements[n] = String.valueOf( n );
                }

                JList list = new JList( elements );
                list.setDragEnabled( true ); //If I disable this line, the I get smooth scrolling, but I can't drag items to re-order them
                list.setDropMode( DropMode.INSERT );
                final TransferHandler transferHandler = new TransferHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public int getSourceActions( JComponent c ) {
                        return TransferHandler.MOVE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Transferable createTransferable( JComponent c ) {
                        return new StringSelection( "Hey there" );
                    }
                };
                list.setTransferHandler( transferHandler );

                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                JPanel borderPanel = new JPanel();
                borderPanel.add( scrollPane );
                borderPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 40, 40, 40, 40 ) );
                frame.setContentPane( borderPanel );
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible( true );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some searching and it turns out this is a known bug:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6710705

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Drop Demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dropmodedemo.html) example from the Swing tutorial. It highlight the row as you drag the mouse towards the bottom. Once the highlight is on the last row it will scroll automatically.

If the mouse is outside the bounds of the JList there is no scrolling because the panel is not a drop target.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just tried the Java Web Start demo, and it behaves the same way as my test case - it scrolls a few rows when I get to the top or bottom of the JList, but then it doesn't move until I jiggle my mouse around. I'll try on Windows and see if the behavior is different.

Comment: I just tried it on Windows 7 and it worked as expected (scrolled smoothly). I guess this is a problem with the Mac OS X Java implementation. I'm running 1.7.0_25-b15 on the mac, 1.7.0_25-b16 on Windows.

Comment: I was using JDK7 with Windows 7 to test the demo.

Comment: If you have a Mac available, you'll see the problem. I reported this as a bug to Oracle.